# JQuery - How can I check my cards in memory game?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a course where I learn JS+JQuery and I have to write a memory game. I want to check if the turned cards are in the same classes so I can delete them and count the points, but I just cannot do it. I tried a lot of ways but I cannot figure it out.
I tried with .is(), === but nothing...

Here's my code:

```js
let gameArea;
let size = 6;
let card_size = 600 / size;

let images = ['arbalest', 'armored', 'arms', 'cannoner', 'cataphract', 'cavalier', 'centurion', 'champion', 'composite',
  'conquistador', 'eagle', 'heavy', 'heavyhorse', 'hussar', 'knight', 'legion', 'paladin', 'skirmisher'
];

$(function() {
  gameArea = $('<div></div>');
  gameArea.appendTo('body');
  gameArea.attr('id', 'gameArea');

  drawMap();

  gameArea.on("click", "div", function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is(".unturned")) {
      $(e.target).removeClass("unturned");
    }

    let unturnedCardNum = $("#gameArea").find("div:not(.unturned)").length;
    if (unturnedCardNum === 3) {
      $("#gameArea").find("div:not(.unturned)").addClass("unturned");
    }

    //I'd like to check here
  });
});

function generate() {
  let generatedImage = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
  if ($("#gameArea").find(`.${generatedImage}`).length === 2) {
    images = images.filter(function(e) {
      return e !== generatedImage
    });
    generatedImage = generate();
  }

  return generatedImage;
}

function drawMap() {
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      let pic = $('<div></div>');
      let shuffledImages = generate();

      pic.addClass(shuffledImages);
      pic.addClass("unturned");
      pic.css({
        width: card_size,
        height: card_size,
        top: i * card_size,
        left: j * card_size
      });
      pic.appendTo(gameArea);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you assign the strings in the `images` array as a class to the cards? And - after having removed the `unturned`-class from it - will that be the only class name an opened card will have?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the string in the `images` array will have been assigned to the associated card as a class name and that, after removing the "unturned" class, this will be the only class name left then maybe the following might help you:

Inside the `$("#gameArea").on("click"...)` function replace the lines

```
let unturnedCardNum = $("#gameArea").find("div:not(.unturned)").length;
if (unturnedCardNum === 3) {
      $("#gameArea").find("div:not(.unturned)").addClass("unturned");
}
```

with

```
let unturnedCards = $("#gameArea").find("div:not(.unturned)");
switch(unturnedCards.length){
 case 3:
  unturnedCards.addClass("unturned");
  break;
 case 2:
  if (unturnedCards[0].className===
      unturnedCards[1].className){
   console.log("you found a pair!");
   // score[currentPlayer]++;
  }
}
```

**Further hint:**
Instead of calling the `generate()` function recursively, you could simply shuffle an array made up of two copies of the `images` array by using a Fisher-Yates algorithm:

```
function shuffle(a,n){ // shuffle array a in place (Fisher-Yates)
 let m=a.length;
 n=n||m-1;
 for(let i=0,j;i<n;i++){
  j=Math.floor(Math.random()*(m-i)+i);
  if (j-i) [ a[i],a[j] ] = [ a[j],a[i] ]; // swap 2 array elements
 }
}
```